# Change label name in Blogger

Tags: blogger

Is there a way to change the name of a Label in Blogger (aka Blogspot) directly?

Labels are essentially tags placed on a blog entry.

If I have a label, "Fun", on several blog posts, and I would like to change it to "Funny", I would now have to go to Edit Posts section, and click on the label "Fun" (on left, which lists all posts tagged with "Fun"), which then lists all blog entries tagged "Fun".

Then, I would have to go to each one, add new label "Funny" to ALL posts listed.  Then once that's done, go through the same list and remove label "Fun".

This seems tedious and quite painful to do a simple label rename.  Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the edit posts screen, click the label to select all posts with it applied and add the new label to all of them (Label actions -> New label). Then just delete the label.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the simple steps to sort out this problem:

1. Go to Blogger Dashboard > Posts
2. Check the very top box, your all posts will be selected.
3. Click on "Label selected post icon" next to "check box" it appears like an arrow.
4. A label list will open, Click on "Fun"
5. Now, you can see your all posts are having "Fun" label
6. Go back to "label selected posts icon" and click on "New label"
7. A window will open, write "Funny" in the column and hit the "ok"

Now, you can see the all posts which were having the label "fun" became "funny"

Answer (score 0):

In today's date [acc. 2022] you have to select 'Manage' then select Square box upon all it's showing, after check it, all posts will be checked! now > click on 'Apply labels on Selected posts' (left to delete icon), then you'll be asked to 'Add a label' name, then type your preferred name, select it. Your new name will be Updated! and old one will gone by itself.